# iOS Universal Links & Responsys Email Integration

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links

We have universal links implemented and are able to deeplink our users from website to App. Lets say our domain is xyz.com

The challenge we are facing is with Deeplinking our Email traffic to our App. Our marketing team uses Responsys and the marketing email we send have links in them with domain xyzemail.com. When the user clicks on these links they user gets redirected to our actual domain xyz.com

My question is what needs to be done so that email links also deeplink to our App when users clicks on email links with domain xyzemail.com?

Trying to Deeplink traffic from Emails to MobileApps

Not sure how to do this without using services of a vendor like Branch or Appsflyer

Currently when the user clicks on xyzemail.com links we open the actual page on xyz.com on safari browser

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the universal links **don't handle redirects**.
The only way to make it work is to host the `apple-app-site-association` file on that exact domain name "xyzemail.com" from the link, and add it to the entitlements file.
It doesn't matter which app is showing the link (an e-mail client or another app), it will work from all apps.

[Related documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/setting_up_an_app_s_associated_domains?language=objc)

Comment: The App only understands the URL pattern for xyz.com and not xyxemail.com. See sample link below. So how will we handle that?                                                       
 Email Link -  https://xyzemail.com/pub/cc?_ri_=X0Gzc2X%3DYQpglLjHJlTQGtzg2w2PzehUnjftTP754N3W6LGzbJA1zbswm99ILWXrL8Lam6Jd6o2qVXtpKX%3DSTSCCWCT&
Redirected Website Link - 
https://xyx.com/store/brand/ugg/5042?isRedirect=true&mcid=EM_BP_Productcampaign_201906_BTCUgg_Offer

Comment: The redirect is not supported. To support both domains, you need to serve 2 apple-app-site-association files: one from xyz.com and one from xyzemail.com

Answer (score 0):

Include xyzemail.com to your supported applinks in Xcode project.

Via `Capabilities -> Associated Domains` target setting.

You also need to put the app association file on xyzemail.com

Comment: I tried that but it did not work. Would I also need to put the app association file on xyzemail.com ?